# TypeError: prevUserFavourites.concat is not a function

Tags: reactjs

```
export function FavouritecContextProvider(props) {
  const [userFavourites, setUserFavourites] = useState([]);

  function addFavouriteHandler(favouriteMeetup) {
    setUserFavourites((prevUserFavourites) => {
      return prevUserFavourites.concat(favouriteMeetup);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What would be the value of the `favouriteMeetup`?

Comment: const FavouritesContext = createContext({
    favourites: [],
    totalFavourites: 0,
    addFavourite: (favouriteMeetup) => {},
   
  });

Comment: Would you mind if you could make a sandbox where you can show full code. If you like you can use https://codesandbox.io/ . This will make easier to understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: https://8zhbw.csb.app/

Comment: I have created a sandbox in the code there is a To Favourite button when clicking on that getting the error

Comment: The error is because `prevUserFavourites` is `boolean` value, let say `false` and there is no method as `concat` on the boolean value. `concat` is an array method...

Comment: Because you are returning `false` from the function `itemIsFavouriteHandler`, So this will initialize the value of the `userFavourites` as `false` which is creating problem...

Comment: What are you trying to do with `itemIsFavouriteHandler` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem that your code has is that you are setting the state of the `userFavourites` as `false`

```
function itemIsFavouriteHandler(meetupId) {
  setUserFavourites((prevUserFavourites) => {
    return false; /*userFavourites.some(meetup=>meetup.id === meetupId);*/
  });
}
```

which changes the `userFavourites` state from an `array` type to boolean value `false`.

So when you function `addFavouriteHandler` runs then It will get the state of `prevUserFavourites` as `false`.

Since, **[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** is a method of `array` and you can't use on boolean value.

---

You just have to return either `true` or `false` if the element is present in `userFavourites` array or not. There is no need to mutate state here as

**`SOLUTION`**

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
function itemIsFavouriteHandler(meetupId) {
    return userFavourites.some((meetup) => meetup.id === meetupId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it is working fine now.